# Setting the Combo box drop down list

Tags: winapi, driver

I am working on printer driver. In this driver I am hooking to GDI calls such as DrvTextOut, DrvBitBlt … etc to get the drawing information. In this Renderer I am displaying a UI with combo box. I could display the UI and combo box.

But the problem is: when I hook to note pad, the drop down list in the combo box will display all the element i.e. it will display all the element without scroll bar. I tried to set the scroll bar height in the UI designer.

But if I hook to Microsoft Word, then drop down will list only 5 items with scroll bar.
Please let me know how to limit the combo box height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CB_SETMINVISIBLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) lets you indicate how many items should be visible.  (The MIN part sounds a little misleading according to the MSDN description.)